# How do I get every item inside a div with overflow?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and I apologize to maybe confusing class names but I managed to scramble this simple menu. It works fine when window is wide and tall enough to fit everything.

I want to achieve the following:

My topnav is always fixed on the page and additional overlay menu opens when MENU icon is activated, I want my overlay menu to take all of the remaining space bellow my fixed topnav and have an overflow when needed and there is no enough space to display all and it works to some extent. But when you zoom in it or if there were a lot of items listed it doesn't display all of them and I can't get to the bottom link but it does when I remove my topnav  which I need fixed to the top. I tried many things but I can't get it to work. I would like a CSS solution if possible.

Thanks in advance

```js
function toggleNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("overlay-navbar");

  if (nav.style.width === "0%") {
    nav.style.width = "100%";
  } else {
    nav.style.width = "0%";
    dropDown();
  }
}

function dropDown() {
  var button = document.getElementById("dropdown-button");
  var dropnav = document.getElementById("dropnav");
  var nav = document.getElementById("overlay-navbar");

  if (dropnav.style.display === "none" && nav.style.width === "100%") {
    dropnav.style.display = "block";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "#0ba397";
  } else {
    dropnav.style.display = "none";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  min-height: 50vh;
  min-width: 10vw;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.topnav-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  transition: 0.3s;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#pagename {
  background-color: #0ba397;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-align: left;
}

#pagename:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: #17a2b8;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
}

.overlay-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.overlay-box {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 25vh;
}

.overlay-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 100px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #0ba397;
}

.dropbtn {
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  /* color: #818181; */
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #0ba397;
}

.overlay-content a {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  /* color: #818181; */
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay-content a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #0ba397;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="topnav-wrapper">
    <nav class="topnav" id="topnav">
      <a href="#home" id="pagename">Title</a>

      <a id="menuicon" href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleNav();">MENU</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
  <nav id="overlay-navbar" class="overlay-wrapper" style="width: 0%;">
    <div class="overlay-box"></div>

    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>

      <button 
        class="dropbtn" 
        id="dropdown-button" 
        href="javascript:void(0);" 
        onclick="dropDown();"
      >Content &#187;</button>

      <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropnav" style="display: none;">
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top nav is pushing the `.overlay-wrapper` downwards. If you give the top nav a fixed height (for example `50px`) you can subtract that amount from the height of the `.overlay-wrapper`:

```css
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

For responsiveness you can modify the fixed height (and the calculation) with media queries.

**Working example:**

```js
function toggleNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("overlay-navbar");

  if (nav.style.width === "0%") {
    nav.style.width = "100%";
  } else {
    nav.style.width = "0%";
    dropDown();
  }
}

function dropDown() {
  var button = document.getElementById("dropdown-button");
  var dropnav = document.getElementById("dropnav");
  var nav = document.getElementById("overlay-navbar");

  if (dropnav.style.display === "none" && nav.style.width === "100%") {
    dropnav.style.display = "block";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "#0ba397";
  } else {
    dropnav.style.display = "none";
    button.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  min-height: 50vh;
  min-width: 10vw;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.topnav-wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  transition: 0.3s;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#pagename {
  background-color: #0ba397;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-align: left;
}

#pagename:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: #17a2b8;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
}

.overlay-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.overlay-box {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 25vh;
}

.overlay-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 100px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #0ba397;
}

.dropbtn {
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  /* color: #818181; */
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: white;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #0ba397;
}

.overlay-content a {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  /* color: #818181; */
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay-content a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #0ba397;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="topnav-wrapper">
    <nav class="topnav" id="topnav">
      <a href="#home" id="pagename">Title</a>

      <a id="menuicon" href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleNav();">MENU</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
  <nav id="overlay-navbar" class="overlay-wrapper" style="width: 0%;">
    <div class="overlay-box"></div>

    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>
      <a>Link</a>

      <button 
        class="dropbtn" 
        id="dropdown-button" 
        href="javascript:void(0);" 
        onclick="dropDown();"
      >Content &#187;</button>

      <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropnav" style="display: none;">
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Link</a>
        <a>Last Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```